# java Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpeg) ceases processing for long video files

Tags: java, ffmpeg, runtime.exec

I'm using Java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpeg)` to execute an `ffmpeg` command to transcode video from any format to mp4 format. When command starts, `ps -ef` shows ffmpeg process and `top` shows that ffmpeg uses most of cpu (90%). When input video for ffmpeg is short (less than 4 mn) the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpeg)` command runs well. But when trying to transcode full HD video that ffmpeg command need more than 10 minutes to be complete, an unknown problem happens around 5 minutes after ffmpeg command starts. `ps -ef` command still shows ffmpeg process even after many hours, but `top` command shows that ffmpeg process doesn't use more that 1% of cpu. So `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpeg)` never finishes.

Comment: can you post the code that executs ffmpeg. Is it only `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpeg)` or is it more?

Comment: Does `ffmpeg` output anything to the console when run without Java? If it does, you have to read the output of `ffmpeg` in Java or pass an option to suppress `ffmpeg` from printing anything to the console if it has one.

Comment: ffmpeg is likely stopping because the buffer for its stdout is full, read http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: Here is the code that I use:
String ffmpegCmd = "ffmpeg -i /data/tmp/o4135_9436603.divx -y -ac 1 -acodec libfaac -vcodec h264 -vf yadif=1:-1:0 -b:a 120k -b:v 2000k -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*2) o4135_1136603.mp4;
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpegCmd);
proc.waitFor();

Comment: In fact I'm using BufferedReader er = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream())); to read ffmpeg output

Comment: But you use only error stream, you have to read `proc.getOutputStream()` too. Can you show the code you use?

Comment: I followed Alexey Ivanov suggestion by adding "-v quiet" in ffmpeg command, It solved my problem. Thank you all

Comment: *"by adding "-v quiet" in ffmpeg command, It solved my problem"*  Only to add a new problem 'ignoring output'.  The best advice is to implement *all* the recommendations in the article linked by @Joni.  It covers the better way suggested by Alexey (consume the output) & gives other tips.  BTW - please join us in the 3rd millennium and use `ProcessBuilder` rather than `Runtime.exec()`..

Comment: You need to show more of your Java code.